# 3D algorithm for clamping a model to view frustum

Tags: algorithm, 3d, webgl

What would be an efficient approach for constraining an object so that it's always at least partially intersecting the view frustum?

The use case is that when viewing a model I want to clamp camera panning, as well as model translation, so that the view frustum is never looking at empty space.

One approach I tried was to wrap the model objects in bounding volumes, then enforce the constraint when those fall outside the frustum. I've tried bounding boxes so far, but am considering using a minimal convex hull.

The problem is that that when you zoom in close enough, it's still possible to be looking at empty space within the boundary, as shown in the attached diagram.

This is for a WebGL application, so needs to be fairly efficient in JavaScript, and also for thousand of vertices.

[image]

Comment: should this be geometrically perfect solution or just simple approximation?

Comment: Would have to be an approximation I guess, because testing against the actual vertices of the meshes wouldn't scale up too well in JavaScript. Open to suggestions on both perfect and approximate though, maybe I can find optimisations..

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would have a aabb tree of your mesh, and then you can recursively project on camea/screen until you get an intersection ?

http://www.codersnotes.com/algorithms/projected-area-of-an-aabb

edit: it's just frustum culling algo against aabtree does anyway, so looking for optimized solution, is looking for optimized frustum culling things

https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/view-frustum-culling/
http://www2.in.tu-clausthal.de/~zach/teaching/cg_literatur/vfc_bbox.pdf

Comment: Yeah I will try that, since I actually do have an AABB tree in place, thanks Tuan

Answer (score 1):

As general approximation is possible I would try the point cloud. First create a list of points - either by every Nth mesh vertex or every Nth face centre. With N being for example 10. Once you have this point array all you do is check if any of points is in frustum while updating its orientation. If not then this means that user moved or rotated the camera too much and you need to restore last acceptable orientation.

I know that this may seem quite ridiculous but I think that it is fairly easy to implement and frustum checking of vertex is just couple of multiplications per plane. It will be not perfect though.

You can also make frustum a little smaller to ensure that there is some border around the object.

Comment: Oooh good idea. And then from there it could be enhanced to use only the most extreme points from the mesh, or find a good distribution within those mesh points.